# is there a way to know why php mail function returns false (it happens 'sometimes')

Tags: php, debugging, function, email

I'm calling php function mail, but it's returning `false` about 5% - 10% of the times, and it's driving me crazy.

I guess from the php side everything is well configured because (correct me if i'm wrong) if not the function should fail every single time.

So the question is how can i know the reason of this behavior? What can i do to debug this?

Comment: Does the email get through when `mail` returns `false`?

Comment: No, the email doesn't get through.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like PHP's build in `mail` for that reason. But my failure rate was below 1%.

I suggest using [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) as described in this [article](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/et073006.htm). It uses an smtp-server to send emails. If an error occurs, you'll get a real error message.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons is e.g. badly constructed From:

```
 Company Ltd. <company@gamil.com>
  => error (false)  - dot is problem

 "Company Ltd." <company@gamil.com>
  => OK (true)
```